# Data First connection with Oracle 64 bit

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio, database-connection

I have an Oracle(12g x64) database that I am trying to connect to using EF (6.x.x) data first approach in an MVC application. However I get a BadImageFormatException.

[image]

I am running everything x64. "Any CPU" is changed to x64. IIS AppPool "Allow 32-bit apps" is set set to false. Project Platform is set to x64
The same environment works fine with plain ADO.NET connections.

Has anyone successfully achieved this?

EDIT:

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32)
 does not provide the answer. I am getting the error only when trying to connect through Server Explorer. Plus, I am using everything x64 to work with my other project. If I install another (x86) client and/or change paths of the current client and dlls it will mess up everything for the other project also.
I have installed the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework nuget packages in my MVC (current) Project. So it removes the requirement for a x86 client.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BadImageFormatException. This will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32)

Comment: Clearly written that you are using 32 bit oracle client. Install 64 bit oracle client

Comment: There's no 32-bit client installed on my computer. Like I said, I am using a x64 client. Even the data access assembly (that I am using in another webforms application) is coming from GAC_x64 folder.

Comment: Visual Studio itself is a 32-bit application. If you like to debug your application you have to use the 32-bit Oracle Client.

Comment: The error message does not match to ODP.NET Managed Driver, i.e. `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`. Check carefully your references and namespaces in your project.

Comment: What do you mean by "The same environment works fine with plain ADO.NET connections."?

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit: "If you like to debug your application you have to use the 32-bit Oracle Client." - Not necessarily. I have been using x64 Client and debugging my application all fine, setting the CPU in VS to x64. And Plain ADO.Net connections means when I am not using EntityFramework or not trying to make a connection via server explorer.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But at least in version 2012 you cannot edit your code while debugging in 64-bit mode.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to enumerate the steps.

From here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html

1. Download Entity Framework "Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015 - MSI Installer" This will provide the EF tools. These tools are compiled in x86
2. Download "64-bit ODAC Downloads" I would suggest the "64-bit ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4) for Windows x64" wich has an installation wizard
3. Use Nuget to install Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework nuget packages in your project

[image]

4. Go to your web-->properties--> and set platform target to x64 in Release Mode

[image]

At this point, it should work properly in debug mode and release mode **in your machine**

5. In the IIS server you should only install "64-bit ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4) for Windows x64" and configure the tnsnames file
6. Deploy all the contents of the bin\x64 folder to the IIS server. No further configuration in IIS if it´s an x64 operating system

Hope it helps